# json response parsing with javascript

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

for example json response is like this:

```
{testing:[
    {"title":"Hello","text":"Hello Test!"},
    {"title":"World","text":"World Test!"}
]}
```

how can I parse this json data using jQuery getJSON and jQuery.each function to print this *data* in separate div tags?

Comment: Euh what date? And please take a look at the related question because this seems like an already asked question.

Comment: sorry not date. DATA. JSON RESPONSE

Comment: That is not valid JSON.  The word `testing` should be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJson(); expects data to be properly formatted, so if u are using php u need to use `json_encode($array)`

and you should be fine, you don't need to parse anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.  It makes a call to the server for your json then loops through the testing array and displays the contents.

```
var data = {id: userId}; //Use null if your server needs no info
jQuery.getJSON( "/mylink/getjson", data, function(json){
    if(typeof(json.testing) != "undefined"){
        $(json.testing).each(function(){
            document.write(this.title);
            document.write(this.text);
        });
    }
})
```